# Colors not rendering with plotly choropleth

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I'm having trouble getting colors to render on RStudio using Plotly. I'm using the most updated version of R and all of my packages are updated.

Here is the code:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(rvest))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(gender))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(genderdata))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggrepel))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(janitor))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(maps))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(usmap))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(plotly))




# Creates variable to hold Wikipedia link

RawElectionData <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_United_States_presidential_election"

# Creates variable to hold and scrape data for the 2016 election from the Wikipedia page

ElectionData <- read_html(RawElectionData) %>% 
  html_node(xpath = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/div[37]/table') %>% 
  html_table(fill=TRUE) %>% clean_names() %>% as_tibble()

# Cleaning of the data

ElectionData <- ElectionData %>% 
  rename(State = x,
         ClintonRaw = hillary_clinton_democratic,
         TrumpRaw = donald_trump_republican) %>% 
  select(State, ClintonRaw, TrumpRaw) %>% 
  slice(-c(1,10,22,23,32,33,34,58)) %>% 
  mutate(State=replace(State, State== "Maine (at-lg)", "Maine"),
         State=replace(State, State== "Nebraska (at-lg)", "Nebraska"),
         ClintonRaw=parse_number(ClintonRaw),
         TrumpRaw=parse_number(TrumpRaw),
         PercentTrump=round(TrumpRaw/(TrumpRaw+ClintonRaw)*100,2))

#Save data

write_csv(ElectionData, path="ElectionDataChpt2.csv")

ElectionDataWithHover <- ElectionData
ElectionDataWithHover$hover <- with(
  ElectionDataWithHover, 
  paste(State, "\n", "Percent Trump: ", PercentTrump, "%")
  )

boundaries<- list(color=toRGB("white"), width=2)

projection <- list(
  scope = 'usa', 
  projection = list(type='albers usa'), 
  showlakes = TRUE, 
  lakecolor=toRGB('white')
  )

plotattempt2 <- plot_geo(
  ElectionDataWithHover,
  locationmode= 'USA-states') %>% 
  add_trace(
    z = ~PercentTrump,
    text = ~hover,
    locations = ~State,
    color = ~PercentTrump,
    colors = 'Reds') %>% 
  colorbar(title = "Percent of Trump Voters" ) %>% 
  layout(title='Percentage of Trump Voters by State (2016)', geo = projection)

plotattempt2
```

When I run it, I don' get any errors, but the colors on the actual plotly choropleth don't show. This is the output.
[The output remains the same regardless of whether I'm using the RStudio viewer or viewing the output in browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSl1A.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need the code for each state. Adding the code (taking from https://plot.ly/r/choropleth-maps/) to your dataset:

```
ElectionDataWithHover_df <- structure(list(State = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", 
"California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", 
"Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", 
"Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", 
"Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", 
"Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", 
"New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", 
"Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", 
"Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", 
"West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"), ClintonRaw = c(729547, 
116454, 1161167, 380494, 8753788, 1338870, 897572, 235603, 4504975, 
1877963, 266891, 189765, 3090729, 1033126, 653669, 427005, 628854, 
780154, 357735, 1677928, 1995196, 2268839, 1367716, 485131, 1071068, 
177709, 284494, 539260, 348526, 2148278, 385234, 4556124, 2189316, 
93758, 2394164, 420375, 1002106, 2926441, 252525, 855373, 117458, 
870695, 3877868, 310676, 178573, 1981473, 1742718, 188794, 1382536, 
55973), TrumpRaw = c(1318255, 163387, 1252401, 684872, 4483810, 
1202484, 673215, 185127, 4617886, 2089104, 128847, 409055, 2146015, 
1557286, 800983, 671018, 1202971, 1178638, 335593, 943169, 1090893, 
2279543, 1322951, 700714, 1594511, 279240, 495961, 512058, 345790, 
1601933, 319667, 2819534, 2362631, 216794, 2841005, 949136, 782403, 
2970733, 180543, 1155389, 227721, 1522925, 4685047, 515231, 95369, 
1769443, 1221747, 489371, 1405284, 174419), PercentTrump = c(64.37, 
58.39, 51.89, 64.29, 33.87, 47.32, 42.86, 44, 50.62, 52.66, 32.56, 
68.31, 40.98, 60.12, 55.06, 61.11, 65.67, 60.17, 48.4, 35.98, 
35.35, 50.12, 49.17, 59.09, 59.82, 61.11, 63.55, 48.71, 49.8, 
42.72, 45.35, 38.23, 51.9, 69.81, 54.27, 69.3, 43.84, 50.38, 
41.69, 57.46, 65.97, 63.62, 54.71, 62.38, 34.81, 47.17, 41.21, 
72.16, 50.41, 75.71), hover = c("Alabama \n Percent Trump:  64.37 %", 
"Alaska \n Percent Trump:  58.39 %", "Arizona \n Percent Trump:  51.89 %", 
"Arkansas \n Percent Trump:  64.29 %", "California \n Percent Trump:  33.87 %", 
"Colorado \n Percent Trump:  47.32 %", "Connecticut \n Percent Trump:  42.86 %", 
"Delaware \n Percent Trump:  44 %", "Florida \n Percent Trump:  50.62 %", 
"Georgia \n Percent Trump:  52.66 %", "Hawaii \n Percent Trump:  32.56 %", 
"Idaho \n Percent Trump:  68.31 %", "Illinois \n Percent Trump:  40.98 %", 
"Indiana \n Percent Trump:  60.12 %", "Iowa \n Percent Trump:  55.06 %", 
"Kansas \n Percent Trump:  61.11 %", "Kentucky \n Percent Trump:  65.67 %", 
"Louisiana \n Percent Trump:  60.17 %", "Maine \n Percent Trump:  48.4 %", 
"Maryland \n Percent Trump:  35.98 %", "Massachusetts \n Percent Trump:  35.35 %", 
"Michigan \n Percent Trump:  50.12 %", "Minnesota \n Percent Trump:  49.17 %", 
"Mississippi \n Percent Trump:  59.09 %", "Missouri \n Percent Trump:  59.82 %", 
"Montana \n Percent Trump:  61.11 %", "Nebraska \n Percent Trump:  63.55 %", 
"Nevada \n Percent Trump:  48.71 %", "New Hampshire \n Percent Trump:  49.8 %", 
"New Jersey \n Percent Trump:  42.72 %", "New Mexico \n Percent Trump:  45.35 %", 
"New York \n Percent Trump:  38.23 %", "North Carolina \n Percent Trump:  51.9 %", 
"North Dakota \n Percent Trump:  69.81 %", "Ohio \n Percent Trump:  54.27 %", 
"Oklahoma \n Percent Trump:  69.3 %", "Oregon \n Percent Trump:  43.84 %", 
"Pennsylvania \n Percent Trump:  50.38 %", "Rhode Island \n Percent Trump:  41.69 %", 
"South Carolina \n Percent Trump:  57.46 %", "South Dakota \n Percent Trump:  65.97 %", 
"Tennessee \n Percent Trump:  63.62 %", "Texas \n Percent Trump:  54.71 %", 
"Utah \n Percent Trump:  62.38 %", "Vermont \n Percent Trump:  34.81 %", 
"Virginia \n Percent Trump:  47.17 %", "Washington \n Percent Trump:  41.21 %", 
"West Virginia \n Percent Trump:  72.16 %", "Wisconsin \n Percent Trump:  50.41 %", 
"Wyoming \n Percent Trump:  75.71 %"), code = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 12L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 22L, 23L, 25L, 24L, 26L, 29L, 33L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 27L, 28L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 46L, 45L, 47L, 49L, 48L, 50L), .Label = c("AK", 
"AL", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "IA", 
"ID", "IL", "IN", "KS", "KY", "LA", "MA", "MD", "ME", "MI", "MN", 
"MO", "MS", "MT", "NC", "ND", "NE", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NV", "NY", 
"OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VA", 
"VT", "WA", "WI", "WV", "WY"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = "data.frame")
```

followed by:

```
plotattempt2 <- plot_geo(
  ElectionDataWithHover_df,
  locationmode= 'USA-states') %>% 
  add_trace(
    z = ~PercentTrump,
    text = ~hover,
    locations = ~code,
    color = ~PercentTrump,
    colors = 'Reds') %>% 
  colorbar(title = "Percent of Trump Voters" ) %>% 
  layout(title='Percentage of Trump Voters by State (2016)', geo = projection)
```